# Does Caching in ColdFusion returns the updated data and Cache again?

Tags: caching, cfquery

No code required.. Just asking. (Please bear with me, English is not my primary language)

Here is the scenario.

I cache a query for 2 hours, and the data is updated in the database before 2 hours are completed. So my question is will the new data from the database will be included in the cache?

Comment: The answer is **NO**. If you specify your cache timeout this is what it will be. It will **NOT** even check the database for the timeout duration.

Comment: @GermannArlington 

So how do I chose your answer as a best answer? :)

Comment: I will have to answer it instead of commenting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is **NO**. If you specify your cache timeout this is what it will be. It will **NOT** even check the database for the timeout duration.

Generally, you should **NOT** use cachedWithin if your data is likely to change because this attribute tells CF to use cached data **without checking** database. If you **used** cachedWithin and you somehow found out that the data has changed you have no easy way of forcing re-query